# UISlider track image disappears on sliding

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uislider

I have this piece of code that creates a custom UISlider. When I fast slide to the end the left_image.png does not show but if I do not slide, it works fine.

```
[sliderFPS setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left_slider.png"]
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sliderFPS setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right_slider.png"]
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[sliderFPS setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb_slider.png"]      
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I have spent more than 2 hours but could not find any solution. Any help will too much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Add this:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))
{
    [[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ios6_slider_minimum_value"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ios6_slider_maximum_value"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 10)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_minimum_value"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_maximum_value"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_button"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: My question is not for IOS version. instead it asks why track image disappears?

Comment: Notice the `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` method. It solves the repeating image issue. And you didn't set stateHighlighted for thumb.